# Cannot obtain correct bone transform matrix data

Tags: c++, directx, animation, fbx

I tried to obtain bone transform matrix for animation implemented with Directx11 and FBX sdk. I found this function in some web resources:

```
fbxCluster->GetLink()->EvaluateGlobalTransform();  // base pose
```

It seems that it is able to recursively calculate global transformation of each bone, thus I don't need to traverse the node tree. However the result obtained from it is weird.

The obtained globalBoneBaseMatrix is used in vertex shader:

```
void MeshImporter::LoadWeight(FbxNode* fbxNode, MeshEntry* mesh)
{
    FbxMesh* fbxMesh = fbxNode->GetMesh();
    int numSkin = fbxMesh->GetDeformerCount(FbxDeformer::eSkin);

    if (numSkin == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    assert(numSkin == 1);

    // Assume only one deformer
    FbxSkin* fbxSkin = static_cast<FbxSkin*>(fbxMesh->GetDeformer(0, FbxDeformer::eSkin));
    int numCluster = fbxSkin->GetClusterCount();
    int numControlPoints = fbxMesh->GetControlPointsCount();
    vector<VertexWeight> tmpWeightList(numControlPoints);

    for (int i = 0; i < numCluster; i++)
    {
        FbxCluster* fbxCluster = fbxSkin->GetCluster(i);
        unsigned int boneIndex = model->skeleton->bones.size();

        assert(fbxCluster->GetLinkMode() == FbxCluster::eNormalize);

        // Read skeleton bones data (transformation matrix of each bone)
        string boneName(fbxCluster->GetLink()->GetName());

        if (!model->skeleton->FindBoneByName(boneName))
        {
            if (boneIndex >= MAXBONE)
            {
                PrintTab("Too many bones to load!!");
            }
            else
            {
                // Read weights of each vertex
                int numIndexInCluster = fbxCluster->GetControlPointIndicesCount();
                int* indicesInCluster = fbxCluster->GetControlPointIndices();
                double* weights = fbxCluster->GetControlPointWeights();

                for (int j = 0; j < numIndexInCluster; j++)
                {
                    tmpWeightList[indicesInCluster[j]].AddBoneData(boneIndex, weights[j]);
                }

                // Normalize weights
                /*for (int inVert = 0; inVert < tmpWeightList.size(); inVert++)
                {
                    tmpWeightList[inVert].Normalize();
                }*/

                // Read animation bone matrix
                XMFLOAT4X4 globalBoneBaseMatrix;
                FbxAMatrix fbxGlobalBoneBaseMatrix = fbxCluster->GetLink()->EvaluateGlobalTransform();

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++)
                        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
                        {
                            globalBoneBaseMatrix.m[r][c] = (float)fbxGlobalBoneBaseMatrix.mData[r][c];

                            PrintTab("Global mat: " +     to_string(fbxGlobalBoneBaseMatrix.mData[r][c]));
                        }
                }

                Bone bone;
                bone.name = boneName;
                bone.globalBoneBaseMatrix = globalBoneBaseMatrix;
                bone.boneIndex = boneIndex;
                bone.fbxNode = fbxNode;

                model->skeleton->bones.push_back(bone);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code reading animation data:

```
// Animation transform data
struct AnimationConstantBuffer
{
    XMFLOAT4X4 meshBoneMatrices[MAXBONE];
};
```

Vertex shader:

```
PixelShaderInput output;
float4 pos = float4(input.pos, 1.0f);

// Test animations
matrix boneTransform = 
    BoneMatrices[input.boneIndices.x] * input.weights.x +
    BoneMatrices[input.boneIndices.y] * input.weights.y +
    BoneMatrices[input.boneIndices.z] * input.weights.z +
    BoneMatrices[input.boneIndices.w] * input.weights.w;

pos = mul(pos, boneTransform);
pos = mul(pos, model);
pos = mul(pos, view);
pos = mul(pos, projection);
output.pos = pos;
...
```

And for testing, I did not update the bone matrix in real time. I'm not sure whether the way I use it is correct, but the rendering result is obviously wrong. There might be other mistakes.